# git send email: Sending email with file as an attchment and not with a patch

Tags: git, email

Suppose I have a file `test.c`. Usually when using `mutt` I can attach a file and send it as an email. But can I do it with `git-sendemail` too? I cannot figure out from the official documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email) and the blogs returned from google.

Answer (score 3):

`git-send-email` sends *patches* corresponding to the commits specified by the *rev-list* argument(s), to mailboxes specified by the `--to`, `--cc` and `--bcc` options.  Each commit will be sent as a separate email, and each email contains all of the information in the commit including the author, commit message and diff.

Side note: `git am` (*apply mail*) is used on the other end to apply a series of patches from a mailbox.

So to answer your question: `git-send-email` is not intended for the sending of arbitrary files.